# Android service stop after updating app

Tags: android, android-service, app-update

I am running a service on regular time interval of 10 sec. It is working fine but when I update the app in google play store , service is not running after that until I restart my phone.

What may be possible cause

Comment: That's completely natural. When the app is updated, first it is closed (and for a short period is uninstalled), so activities and services are destroyed. You should think about a way of restarting the service at every condition, if it is really necessary. Otherwise, it will be started when you start the app (if is that expressly you call it from the Main Activity).

Comment: My service is used for data sync. What if someone updates the app and never open it. Then service will never be started, and user will never get new data. Is there any way to start service after updating the app.

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to catch some of the broadcasts sent by the OS. It could be Network Change, as example. In that case, when the network changes you react to the broadcast by starting your service again. AFAIK there's no official way of doing that because Android doesn't considers that there's something that has to be ever running. But the suggested workaround is to use some broadcasts (thus, new permissions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can receive the [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) broadcast event and then restart your service

Comment: please mark my solution as answer or indicate what is not clear in my answer